# AWS SQS, DLQ in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-sqs

How do I add a DLQ configuration to my SQS configuration? I'm not sure how to integrate a DLQ with my existing queue. I'm using aws messaging and not JMS, so my annotation would be `@SQSListener` for my listener method. I have a config class that has following

```java
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSQSAsync);
    factory.setMaxNumberOfMessages(10);
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer = factory.createSimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    simpleMessageListenerContainer.setQueueStopTimeout(queueStopTimeout*1000);
    simpleMessageListenerContainer.setMessageHandler(messageHandler(amazonSQSAsync));
    return simpleMessageListenerContainer;
}

@Bean
public QueueMessageHandler messageHandler(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync) {
    QueueMessageHandlerFactory queueMessageHandlerFactory = new QueueMessageHandlerFactory();
    queueMessageHandlerFactory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSQSAsync);
    QueueMessageHandler messageHandler = queueMessageHandlerFactory.createQueueMessageHandler();
    return messageHandler;
}

@Bean
public AmazonSQSAsync awsSqsAsync() {
    AmazonSQSAsyncClient amazonSQSAsyncClient  = new AmazonSQSAsyncClient(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain());
    amazonSQSAsyncClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.fromName(region)));
    return new AmazonSQSBufferedAsyncClient(amazonSQSAsyncClient);
}
```

I couldn't find any right documentation to correctly set retries so that if the retries exceed the threshold, the message should go to a dead-letter queue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, setting the `maximum retries`, and `associated DLQ` is done on the `Broker` side, and not configurable as part of the listener.

Then in your code, you will do something like:

```
@SqsListener(value = "MainQueue", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.NEVER)
public void receive(String message, @Header("SenderId") String senderId, Acknowledgment ack) throws IOException {

  ack.acknowledge();  

}
```

---

```
@SqsListener(value = "DLQ-AssociatedWithMain")
public void receiveDlq(String message) throws IOException {

}
```

If Message is NOT acknowledged, then it will be retried for a specific max period, then sent to DLQ.

=== Edited ===

The below for `LocalStack` are suggestions (Never Tested), However LocalStack (Free Version) as of now is supposed to support the AWS CLI:

As such, if you look at the `AWS CLI`: you use `aws create-queue` to create a Queue, and `--attributes` if you wanted to specify DLQ Information, though I believe you must also create the DLQ queue as well before referencing the RN.

```
  create-queue
--queue-name <value>
[--attributes <value>]
[--tags <value>]
[--cli-input-json <value>]
[--generate-cli-skeleton <value>]
```

**DLQ Attribute Details:**

The following attributes apply only to dead-letter queues:

```
RedrivePolicy – The string that includes the parameters for the dead-letter queue functionality of the source queue as a JSON object. The parameters are as follows:
    deadLetterTargetArn – The Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the dead-letter queue to which Amazon SQS moves messages after the value of maxReceiveCount is exceeded.
    maxReceiveCount – The number of times a message is delivered to the source queue before being moved to the dead-letter queue. When the ReceiveCount for a message exceeds the maxReceiveCount for a queue, Amazon SQS moves the message to the dead-letter-queue.
RedriveAllowPolicy – The string that includes the parameters for the permissions for the dead-letter queue redrive permission and which source queues can specify dead-letter queues as a JSON object. The parameters are as follows:
    redrivePermission – The permission type that defines which source queues can specify the current queue as the dead-letter queue. Valid values are:
        allowAll – (Default) Any source queues in this Amazon Web Services account in the same Region can specify this queue as the dead-letter queue.
        denyAll – No source queues can specify this queue as the dead-letter queue.
        byQueue – Only queues specified by the sourceQueueArns parameter can specify this queue as the dead-letter queue.
    sourceQueueArns – The Amazon Resource Names (ARN)s of the source queues that can specify this queue as the dead-letter queue and redrive messages. You can specify this parameter only when the redrivePermission parameter is set to byQueue . You can specify up to 10 source queue ARNs. To allow more than 10 source queues to specify dead-letter queues, set the redrivePermission parameter to allowAll .
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sqs/create-queue.html

---

---

In `LocalStack SQS` Documentation, they have an example of creating an `SQS Queue`:

```
awslocal sqs create-queue --queue-name sample-queue
{
    "QueueUrl": "http://localhost:4566/000000000000/sample-queue"
}
```

So just take this example, create your `DLQ`, then create your `Queue` with `--attributes` to point to the `DLQ RN`.

https://docs.localstack.cloud/aws/sqs/

Hope this helps guide you in the right direction,

==== Edited ===

**Create Queue and DLQ using LocalStack:**

Create DLQ First:

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 sqs create-queue --queue-name MyDLQ --region eu-west-1
```

Response:

```
{
    "QueueUrl": "http://localhost:4566/000000000000/MyDLQ"
}
```

---

Create an `attributes.json` file with the contents below:

```
{
  "RedrivePolicy": "{\"deadLetterTargetArn\":\"arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:000000000000:MyDLQ\",\"maxReceiveCount\":\"1000\"}",
  "MessageRetentionPeriod": "259200"
}
```

---

Create your main queue pointing to a`attributes.json` file:

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 sqs create-queue --queue-name MyMainQueue --attributes file://attributes.json --region eu-west-1
```

Response:

```
{
    "QueueUrl": "http://localhost:4566/000000000000/MyMainQueue"
}
```

Comment: Like when I see the queue creation in AWS there is an option to configure dlq with the queue we're creating. I'll be using localstack for testing, do you have any idea how I can add a dlq with the main queue

Comment: @AdityaK Please see my updated answer on how you could possibly achieve the same Queue-DLQ using LocalStack.   I have not tested it, so I cant say if it will work on LocalStack.  Do update me if it does!

Comment: Please do update me @AdityaK I would love to know if you got LocalStack working with Create queue and DLQ :)

Comment: aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 sqs set-queue-attributes --queue-url http://localstack:4566/000000000000/myTestQueue --attributes "{"RedrivePolicy": "{\"deadLetterTargetArn\": \"arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:000000000000:myTestDLQueue\",\"maxReceiveCount\": \"1\"}","VisibilityTimeout": 5}", I'm getting an error when I try that command. I tried a couple different Json but didn't work. I'm assuming the way I'm writing my Json is wrong

Comment: Tried the same Json attribute while creating a queue. Didn't work

Comment: @AdityaK could you create another question related to creating queue and dlq on SQS local stack.  Maybe someone could help.   Otherwise when I have time I will try it also and see.

Comment: @AdityaK By the way, you can also use code, to create queues and set attributes.  Please see example here https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/1551

Comment: Yeah but for my use-case I need to have a queue present. So yeah I'll probably post another question for that.

Comment: @AdityaK I got it working, please see updated answer :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For testing in localstack this command is needed:

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 sqs set-queue-attributes --queue-url http://localhost:4566/000000000000/<QueueName> --attributes file://dead-letter-queue-config.json
```